# Automatização de processo - Excel - VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, recaptcha

Estou tentando automatizar um processo do meu serviço. Entretanto ao rodar o código ele diz que `"A variável do objeto ou a variável do bloco 'With' não foi definida".`

O que gostaria que ele fizesse é:

- Que identificasse a barra do site onde é para inserir o Cnpj e dentro da celula 3 coluna 1 inserir esse dado.
- Realizar esse processo porém com o os dados do captcha.

  - Dúvida: Como seria possível traduzir ou "burlar" o capthca nessa situação?

````
Sub PullData()

    Dim HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument

    Range("B3:D3").ClearContents

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    ie.navigate "https://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/swb/default.asp?sg_sistema=fundosreg"
    ie.Visible = True

    Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
        DoEvents
    Loop

    HTMLDOC.getElementsByid("txtCNPJNome")(0).Value = Cells(3, 1).Value
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("numRandom")(0).Value = Cells(3, 2).Value
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("btnContinuar")(3).Click


    Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Cells(4, 2) = ie.document.getElementsByName("td")(0).innertext
    Cells(4, 3) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
    Cells(4, 4) = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innertext

    ie.Quit

    Range("A3:D3").WrapText = False

    For Each aba In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        aba.Columns("A:F").AutoFit
    Next

End Sub
```
````

Comment: Você quer um bypass de recaptcha? Veja [neste link uma maneira](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/85mkmm/robot_proof_i_think_not/). Como este captcha que você está utilizando é de imagem, talvez com Visão Computacional e Deep Learning seja possível treinar um algoritmo para resolver isso, mas não com VBA. E não sei de algum que exista para isso.

Comment: Na realidade seria ao contrario jogar os dados na celula e com isso ele inserir os mesmos na aba do formulário

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi bem sua questão, vc quer pegar as informações do formulário e jogar nas células.

Mas nesse momento vc está fazendo o contrário.

```
...
    HTMLDOC.getElementsByid("txtCNPJNome")(0).Value = Cells(3, 1).Value
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("numRandom")(0).Value = Cells(3, 2).Value
...
```

*`Cells(3, n).Value`* tem que estar ao lado esquerdo do sinal de atribuição.